# Capybara, Sweet-Alert, click_button seems to work, but does not trigger the action

Tags: angularjs, capybara, sweetalert

I'm trying to write a test. There is a site with an element and a delete-button, to delete that element. If done manually, it works as expected.

Currently, the test looks like this:

```
visit "/argumentation#!/overview"
expect(page).to have_content("Philosophie")

save_screenshot
click_button "Delete"

save_screenshot
click_button "Yes, delete it!"

save_screenshot
sleep 5

save_screenshot
expect(page).not_to have_content("Philosophie")
```

(Pictures of the screenshots are below).

To make sure, that `click_button "Yes, delete it!"` is actually the same button as displayed in the popup, I added `click_button "Yes, delete it!"` before the `click_button "Delete"`-action. This would happen:

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find button "Yes, delete it!"
```

Does anyone know, why the test is failing?

In other stackoverflow-questions, some asked about the configuration in rails_helper.rb, here is mine:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
```

First screenshot: 
[image]

Second screenshot:
[image]

Third screenshot:
[image]

Fourth screenshot:
[image]

Comment: have you tried with `page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept` ?

Comment: @fabersky I get this error:      Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `switch_to' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Browser:0x0055761e8b8348>
       Did you mean?  switch_to_frame

Comment: It's not a system modal so `switch_to.alert` isn't going to work.  Also, prefer `Session#accept_alert` over driver specific methods when it is a system modal

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: The click_button "Yes, delete it!" is happening too fast. With a delay, it works:

```
click_button "Delete"
sleep 5
click_button "Yes, delete it!"
```

Comment: Does your alert button animate onto the screen?  If it does, that's probably why since the click can miss the button if the button is moving.  Check the library you're using for the alerts and see if there is a way you can disable animations when in the test environment.